# Facebook C# SDK Update Schedule

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/66412) and would like to know what the best approach would be to use it to keep my cached user data up to date?

Currently I am storing these pieces of user information:

- userid
- birthday
- name
- sex
- country
- pic
- pic_square

Has anyone given this any thought or have experience in using the SDK to keep their caches up to date?  And if so, how did u architecture your solution ...

[Also, when responding please inform me of the graph api calls you made etc, fb are so obscure with this data]

Regards
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the facebook subscription feature. This way the facebook will ping your url with the changed data every time the data is changed by the user. it is a push based notification. It allows you to get real time updates for a graph object. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/subscription/

If you are using web forms, implement FacebookSubscriptionsHttpHandler and FacebookSubscriptionVerifier.

For mvc use FacebookSubscriptionReceivedAttribute and FacebookSubscriptionVerifyAttribute

I would highly suggest you too look at the FacebookSubscriptionsHttpHandler source code http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/08cb51f372b5#Source%2fFacebook.Web%2fFacebookSubscriptionsHttpHandler.cs

It contains xml comments on how to use it.

It is a 3 step process.

1. Getting the Facebook app access token.
2. Subscribing to subscriptions
3. receiving and processing subscriptions

Comment: Hi Prabir, Can you give me a quick example on how to use FacebookSubscriptionReceivedAttribute and FacebookSubscriptionVerifyAttribute to subscribe to the users Name, DOB and Country?  I'm using MVC thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example implementation using MVC3:

```
public class SubscriptionController : Controller
{
    private const string SubscriptionVerificationToken = "E5FB84E0-F425-445A-86C8-9FC598E79B1E";
    private const string CallbackUrl = "http://mysite.com/subscription/verify";

    public void Index()
    {
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(FacebookApplication.Current);
        dynamic result = fb.Post(
            string.Format("/{0}/subscriptions", FacebookApplication.Current.AppId), new Dictionary<string, object> 
                {
                    { "object","user"},
                    { "fields","friends" }, 
                    {"callback_url", CallbackUrl }, 
                    { "verify_token", SubscriptionVerificationToken }
                });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [FacebookSubscriptionVerify(SubscriptionVerificationToken)]
    public void Verify(FacebookClient fb)
    {
        FacebookSubscriptionVerifiedResult verifiedResult = new FacebookSubscriptionVerifiedResult();
        verifiedResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [FacebookSubscriptionReceived]
    [ActionName("Verify")]
    public void Receive()
    {
        //handle response
    }

}
```